# redirect query string url to a static url

Tags: .htaccess

I am running into issue with redirecting a url with query string:

`http://mysite.com/a/b/index.html?title=abc` to a one off URL say: `http://mysite.com/xyz/asdf/`

I Have been fumbling around with this for a while and have not found anything that can help me out with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} title=abc [NC]
RewriteRule ^/a/b/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/xyz/asdf/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: yea not sure what is going on. Just redirects to the homepage, but this is the first action in the htaccess.

Comment: Actually just realized there is a mistake, let me post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)title=abc(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^a/b/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/xyz/asdf/? [L,R=302,NC]
```

Remember RewriteRule doesn't match leading slash.

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: the leading slash was the issue! Thanks for your help.